# Traveling to Ireland without visa sticker through UK

Tags: visas, uk, ireland

Let's consider a hypothetical situation :)

I am going through a short-stay business trip through UK into Ireland. My passport requires visa for both countries. I have applied for both and both have been approved. I collected the UK sticker but not Ireland sticker (couldn't make it to the visa center in time before my trip for example).

- Am I breaking the law if I enter Ireland through UK border by land without that sticker? I assume they will at least ask me 'how did you get here' when I exit via plane even if nobody stops me at the UK-Ireland border itself.
- Will it help if I get by email and print the positive visa decision that Irish embassy sends? Is there even such document in existence?
- What are my other options if I can't get the sticker in time at the same place I applied at?

Comment: A UK visa does not automatically allow you to enter the ROI. See https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/government-in-ireland/ireland-and-the-uk/common-travel-area-between-ireland-and-the-uk/#:~:text=People%20with%20UK%20visas%20or%20residence%20permits&text=This%20scheme%20allows%20visitors%20from,are%20endorsed%20with%20'BIVS'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that could happen

> (couldn't make it to the visa center in time before my trip for example)

Then you have no passport, full stop. And entering Ireland/the UK without a passport is of course *impossible* if you require a visa in the first place.

If you use a *keep your passport* service (where you keep your passport while the application is in process and return it to get stamped), and don't return your passport for stamping, your visa application will be **refused**, even if it had been approved in the first place.

> Will it help if I get by email and print the positive visa decision that Irish embassy sends?

This doesn't happen, visa decisions are never sent by email (this will likely only happen in Australia/NZ where all visas are fully electronic, and no stamps are applied) but are carried in sealed letters, along with the **stamped** (or not if refused) travel document to the visa center. Neither you nor the visa center know what the decision is before you get your passport and open it.